# Embedd a xsd file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Right now we have static code to a XML schema file. But now we want to embedd that file

Code right now:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("schema.xsd");
XmlSchema schema = XMLSchema.Read(xReader, new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler));
```

But now I want to have it embedded in a Resouce file. So how do I do.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Resouces.Schema);
XmlSchema schema = XMLSchema.Read(xReader, new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler));
```

This is not the way.

Comment: This seems to work. But have I introduces someting bad here?

StringReader xsdFile = new StringReader(Resources.Schema.ToString());
XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(xsdFile);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Get the assembly that contains the embedded schema
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.schema.xsd"))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    XmlSchema schema = XMLSchema.Read(
        reader, 
        new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single file, just extract it (`GetManifestResourceStream`) and use directly. If you have multiple related files, you'll need to write an `XmlResolver`. I have a resx-based resolver somewhere... You then set this as the `XmlResolver` or an `XmlReaderSettings`, and pass in your `XmlReaderSettings` when calling `XmlReader.Create`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Stream xsdStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("schema.xsd");
```